# The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Shoplist'

Tags: flutter, list, dart

> The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List>)
> The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Shoplist'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.
> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Shoplist'.
> Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: Please fix your post as well as post the actual code.

Comment: Can you show the code so we can help you better?